# javascript return item within return

Tags: javascript

I would like to structure my app like this:

```
APP.open = (function ($) {
  return {
    people: function() {
      return {

        gender: function() {},

        age: function() {}
      }
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

I can get `APP.open.people()`, but when I do: `APP.open.people.gender();` I get `undefined`.

Comment: `APP.open.people().gender();`

Comment: Isn't `APP.open` a function? Just asking, because I'm not really an expert on javascript.

Comment: @Nolonar - `APP.open` is an object, as the function you see is an IIFE that executes immediately and returns an object. `APP.open.people` on the other hand, is **not** an IIFE, and has to be called.

Comment: @adeneo. I see. Looks like I know what I'll be researching tonight, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to achieve what you are asking:
Note the anonymous function wrapping around the people assignment.

```
APP.open = (function ($) {
return {
  people: (function() {
    return {

      gender: function() {},

      age: function() {}
     }
   })()
 };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: this looks interesting. Just one question. How can I extent the people method from another file?

Comment: so what i would like to do is to define `APP.open.people.race()` method from a different file.

Comment: To do that you can use object literal.
`App.open = {  people: {  gender: function(){ ... } }  }`
and from another file you can add methods to people
`App.open.people.race =  function(){ ... }`

Comment: Currently implementation would also work with `App.open.people.race = function(){ ... }` but object literal version would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

APP.open.people().gender();

silly, I over saw this... Thanks guys!